# how to load ActiveX dll from mfc dll

Tags: mfc

Got a third party ActiveX dll which has control dialog for a fan. Would like to access the ACtiveX dll from a MFC dll with APIs, so that be able open the control dialog and access some other functions in the ActiveX. IS this practically easy?., and what resources should be called where?. any examples?. Need to record temperature continuously while no around around.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I liked to get some information about if this is cleanly possible?. i read in msdn need to call AfxEnableOleContainer() in the InitInstance.

Comment: Initially you asked whether this was *"practically easy"*. The answer to that is: It depends. If you know what you're doing, it is. If you don't, it isn't. Consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question to meet this site's expectations.

Comment: please read my own answer in below.

Answer (score 1):

After reading so much at the microsoft site, came up with a MFC dll that its dialog uses an ActiveX control. Also, wrote a MFC and a console applications that by calling dll's opendialog(), I see the dialog launches. I hope I am not causing any memory leak. or causing any resource (de)allocation errors without knowing. so far , things seem to be working.

```
BOOL CDllApp::InitInstance()
{
    CoInitialize(0);
    AfxEnableControlContainer();
    return CWinApp::InitInstance();
}

int CDllApp::ExitInstance()
{
    CoUninitialize();
    return CWinApp::ExitInstance();
}

In another class, in the same mfc dll, i do this.:
void CMyClass::opendialog()
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState( ));
    CMyDialog dlg;
    dlg.DoModal();
}
```